# Swift - Using animateWithDuration to fade CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, fade, cagradientlayer, animatewithduration

I have switch statement controlling my background gradients. It works nicely (the gradients change), however it changes abruptly. I would like for these gradients to fade into each other with a .25 duration. My code attempt at this is below.

**Switch statement that controls the backgrounds:**

```
switch backgroundInput{
case 50...69:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor1, gradientColor2])
case 70...90:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor2, gradientColor3])
case 91...110:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor3, gradientColor4])
case 111...130:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor4, gradientColor5])
case 131...150:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor5, gradientColor6])
case 151...170:
self.view.configureGradient([gradientColor6, gradientColor7])
default:
self.view.configureGradient([lightPurple, lightBlue])
}
```

**Extension that controls the gradients**
*This is where I attempted the animate duration*

```
extension UIView {
private func prepareGradient() -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.zPosition = -1
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    return gradientLayer
}
func configureGradient(colors:[CGColor]) {
    let gradientLayer = prepareGradient()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

How can I adjust my code above to fade the gradientlayers from one to another? (unrelated - is it bad for memory to constantly "add sublayer" on sublayers?)

Comment: Yes, it's bad to constantly add more sublayers. You should create one gradient layer and then modify its properties to update the gradient. Fix that then come back and update your question with the new code, if you still have trouble.

Comment: @robmayoff - Yikes. Glad I caught that! Is the fix here as simple as removing self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer) from the configureGradient function, and moving it into prepareGradient? (I've edited my code above.)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
func configureGradient(colors:[CGColor]) {
    let gradientLayer = prepareGradient()
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    UIView.transitionWithView(self,
                              duration: 0.25,
                              options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
                              animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
                                self?.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

...anyway adding sublayers only to change color is not cool. 
Try to store your gradient layer in your extension:

```
private struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
}

var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    get {
        guard let gLayer = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.gradientLayer) as? CAGradientLayer else { return CAGradientLayer() }
        return gLayer
    }
    set(value) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.gradientLayer, value, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
}
```

May be a UIView subclass is more simple to implement... I think you should do it this way.

Comment: This does work, yes! However, there was a bug in my initial code of continuously stacking sublayers. I am trying to get that worked out in my initial code, and then will try adding this fade back in.